# css step wizard z-index not working

Tags: html, css, wizard

I've coded the step wizard as below.

```css
ul.progress[data-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }

.progress {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

.progress li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.progress .name {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .step {
    color: black;
    border: 3px solid silver;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.progress .step span {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .active .name,
.progress .active .step span {
  
}

.progress .step:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.progress .step:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
    display: none;
}

.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
    display: none;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .done .step:before,
.progress .done .step:after,
.progress .active .step,
.progress .active .step:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .active .step {
    border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
        <div>
            <ul class="progress" data-steps="4">
                <li class="done">
                    <span class="name">Foo</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>1</span></span>
                </li>
                <li class="done">
                    <span class="name">Bar</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>2</span></span>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <span class="name">Baz</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>3</span></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name">Quux</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>4</span></span>
                </li>
                
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

But the z-index doesn't work.
z-index of the class "step" is 10, while the one of "step:before,step:after" is 9.
Why does the "step:after" element , gray line , put above the green circle?
So I don't understand the z-index well.
Thanks.

Comment: z-index only works in positioned elements and your `.step` elements aren't

Comment: why doesn't the .step element z-index work?

Comment: thanks for your helping.

Comment: You need to set the position property to something other than the default of static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one.
1. I've added the z-index  in .active .step span and and made it to circle with background.

```
.progress .active .name,
.progress .active .step span {
  position:relative;
  z-index:11;
  opacity: 1;
}

.progress .active .step span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 35px;
    height: 29px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 12;
    margin:-2px 0 0 -2px;
    padding-top:6px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

2. I've added the lower z-index in .active .step:after than .step.

   .progress .active .step:after {
        z-index:8;
       }

Please see whole code below;

```css
ul.progress[data-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }

.progress {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

.progress li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.progress .name {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .step {
    color: black;
    border: 3px solid silver;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.progress .step span {
    opacity: 0.3;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:4px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}


.progress .active .step span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 35px;
    height: 29px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 12;
    margin:-2px 0 0 -2px;
    padding-top:6px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}


.progress .active .name,
.progress .active .step span {
  position:relative;
  z-index:11;
  opacity: 1;
}

.progress .step:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.progress .step:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
    display: none;
}

.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
    display: none;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .done .step:before,
.progress .done .step:after,
.progress .active .step,
.progress .active .step:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}


.progress .active .step:after {
   z-index:8;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .active .step {
    border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
            <ul class="progress" data-steps="4">
                <li class="done">
                    <span class="name">Foo</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>1</span></span>
                </li>
                <li class="done">
                    <span class="name">Bar</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>2</span></span>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <span class="name">Baz</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>3</span></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name">Quux</span>
                    <span class="step"><span>4</span></span>
                </li>
                
            </ul> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve the result by **not given** the `.step` class a `z-index` and then giving the `:before` and `:after` element a **negative** `z-index`.

*I believe* that giving the `.step` class a `z-index` value affects its `:before` and `:after` elements. For more details on that please see [Michael Coker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123505/michael-coker) great technical explanation in the comments below.

If there are other elements on the page like a background, give the **background** a `z-index` value of `-2` like I did with the `body`

```css
body {
      background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
      z-index:-2;
}

ul.progress[data-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
ul.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }

.progress {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #000;

}

.progress li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.progress .name {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

.progress .step {
    color: black;
    border: 3px solid silver;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.progress .step span {
    opacity: 1;
}

.progress .active .name,
.progress .active .step span {
  
}

.progress .step:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progress .step:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
    display: none;
}

.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
    display: none;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .done .step:before,
.progress .done .step:after,
.progress .active .step,
.progress .active .step:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.progress .done .step,
.progress .active .step {
    border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="progress" data-steps="4">
    <li class="done">
      <span class="name">Foo</span>
      <span class="step"><span>1</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="done">
      <span class="name">Bar</span>
      <span class="step"><span>2</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <span class="name">Baz</span>
      <span class="step"><span>3</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="name">Quux</span>
      <span class="step"><span>4</span></span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I believe that giving the .step class a z-index value affects it's :before and :after elements"* that's correct. Giving an element a `z-index` starts a new stacking order, and all of it's children `z-index`es will start from the parent's. The `:after` element is a child of `.step`, so it's `z-index` will be relative to the parent's. If the parent (`.step`) has a `z-index`, it's children can not have a lower `z-index`. Your fix is the way to do it.

Comment: But the z-index of the "before" is less than the "step", why does "before" element put above the "step" circle"?

Comment: @AndrewLi see my comment above. Assigning a z-index to a parent element starts a new stacking order/context for it's children. The only way to get a child to have a lower z-index is to remove the z-index from the parent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you very much! That's a much better explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set z-index of before and after element to -1.

Comment: My background z-index is 0, so if the z-index is -1, the line wouldn't be displayed.